# How to create a Rule to create a new entity of type Comment and a body with tokens?

Tags: 7, rules, comments, tokens

Using **drupal 7** and the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, I'm trying to *"create a new entity"* of type `comment`. What it's strange, is that although all the other fields accept tokens, *"the main body text"* doesn't.
Tokens are considered as simple text.

Anyone experienced this and know how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Comment # 10](https://www.drupal.org/node/1281912#comment-5824742) of the Rules (support) issue titled "[Access and Set Comment extra fields](https://www.drupal.org/node/1281912) ". It includes a Rule example that looks like so:

```
{ "rules_test" : {
    "LABEL" : "Comment bot",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : [ "node_update" ],
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "node" ], "field" : "field_status" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "entity_create" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "comment",
            "param_subject" : "zzz",
            "param_node" : [ "node" ],
            "param_author" : [ "node:author" ],
            "param_comment_body" : { "value" : {
                "value" : "This text will be replaced in the next action.",
                "format" : "filtered_html"
              }
            }
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "new_comment" : "New comment" } }
        }
      },
      { "data_set" : {
          "data" : [ "new-comment:comment-body:value" ],
          "value" : [ "node:field-status" ]
        }
      }
   ]
  }
}
```

The clue to solve your issue (= work around?) is to use that last Rules Action starting with "`data_set`".

Comment: Thank you for your reply!  
As a workaround it works! It's strange that this is not implemented by default by the Rules module.

Comment: For sure, I was thinking about ways to improve this (for example, translation support is not available, neither HTML support) but I think now it's the best answer, marked as accepted :)

Comment: @Kropot : merci for the accept. About "translation support", not sure what exactly you mean by that. But maybe you should create a new question as a followup to this one? If it makes sense, even with some link to this question also?