# How to add a comment form in VBO to add the same comment to mutiple nodes?

Tags: comments, views

I am using "Comments" as a note option. I want to let users add the same comment to multiple nodes with the [Views Bulk Operations (VBO)](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module.

How do I get the "Add Comment Form" in VBO to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Step 1

Use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to create a Rules Component, which includes whatever Rules Conditions you might need (if any), and with a Rules Action to **create an entity**, of type "Comment", whereas you specify some relevant parameters for that Rules Component, such as:

- The node to which the comment is to be added.
- The relevant options for the actual comment (such as the actual text of the comment).

Below is an example of a Rules Action that creates a comment (in Rules export format, use the Rules UI to import it in your own site):

```
{ "rules_add_a_comment_to_a_node" : {
    "LABEL" : "Add a comment to a node",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : {
      "comment_node" : { "label" : "Node to add comment", "type" : "node" },
      "comment_body" : { "label" : "Comment body", "type" : "text_formatted" },
      "comment_subject" : { "label" : "Comment subject", "type" : "text" }
    },
    "IF" : [
      { "user_has_role" : {
          "account" : [ "site:current-user" ],
          "roles" : { "value" : { "2" : "2" } }
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "entity_create" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "comment",
            "param_subject" : [ "comment-subject" ],
            "param_node" : [ "comment-node" ],
            "param_author" : [ "site:current-user" ],
            "param_comment_body" : [ "comment-body" ]
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "comment_created" : "Created comment" } }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

#### Step 2

Create a view of the nodes to which some comment is to be added. Then transform that view into a view that uses [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations), and use the technique documented in "[How to use Rules to create a custom bulk operation for a VBO view?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/88)". In doing so, you'll then be able to use the Rules Component from Step 1.

PS: this answer is for D7 ...

Comment: @GirishCholayill : I'm about sure that all you need to do is to change "text_formatted" (in line 8 of my exported rule sample) to just "text" (which you can also do I think in the Rules UI, by changing the data type there). Maybe also have a look at the sample rule in [this answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/218186/how-to-create-a-rule-to-create-a-new-entity-of-type-comment-and-a-body-with-toke/218190#218190) (there is a way to do this, I just don't know anymore by heart).

Comment: I did try that, but it was giving me error. That's alright, I'll check it up. Thanks a lot for the help. Appreciate it.

Comment: Its working now, it was an error in my content editor.

Comment: @GirishCholayill : aha, it was only that ... time to cleanup some "extended discussions" comments around here (= delete them), before a mod moves them to chat (which I don't like at all). Greetings!